# Insert many documents after result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following code to query the collection and get some results.

```
var subquery = {"shipdate" : { 
    "$gte" : 19960101, 
    "$lt" : 19960401 } 
};

var eachsupp = db.lineitems.aggregate([
    { $match : subquery },
    { $project : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "revenue" : {$multiply : ["$extendedprice", {$subtract : [1, "$discount"] }] },
        "supplier_no" : "$partsupp.supplier.suppkey",
        "name" : "$partsupp.supplier.name",
        "address" : "$partsupp.supplier.address",
        "phone" : "$partsupp.supplier.phone" }},
    { $group : {
        _id : "$supplier_no",
        total_revenue : { $sum : "$revenue" },
        name : {$first : "$name"},
        address : {$first : "$address"},
        phone : {$first : "$phone"} }}
]);
```

After that I have this result:

```
{ "_id" : 5, "total_revenue" : 39995.208, "name" : "Supplier#000000005", "address" : "Gcdm2rJRzl5qlTVzc", "phone" : "21-151-690-3663" }
{ "_id" : 138, "total_revenue" : 37736.3465, "name" : "Supplier#000000138", "address" : "utbplAm g7RmxVfYoNdhcrQGWuzRqPe0qHSwbKw", "phone" : "29-533-434-6776" }
```

And more like that. And I want to insert that in a tmp collection. Like this:

```
db.tmp.insert(eachsupp.result);

db.tmp.find().sort({total_revenue : -1}).limit(1);
```

But I have an error because it can't insert.

```
db.tmp.insert(eachsupp.result);
2016-04-17T23:12:20.683+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: no object passed to ins
ert! : DBCollection.prototype.insert@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:226:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your aggregation

```
{ $sort: { total_revenue: -1 } },
{$out: "eachsupp"}
```

Sort will sort you result as per total_revenue and
Out will write it to new collection.

Answer (score 1):

I think replace `db.tmp.insert(eachsupp.result);`

with this  `eachsupp.forEach(function(document){db.tmp.insert(document)});`

`eachsupp.result` is throw exception

`eachsupp` is cursor,iterate cursor with loop and insert each one